# Dont allow a button to break without word

Tags: html, css

Let's say you have a help text with a button like:

```
<label>This is a short help text <button>(?)</button></label>
```

If you shrink the window size, at some point a line break happens, and the button `?` is alone at the second line.

```
This is a short help text
(?)
```

So the UX Team said, the `(?)` button should't be alone at second line, instead the last word and button.

```
This is a short help
text (?)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it with regular CSS?

Because we are using React, I suggested to break the sentence, and create a non breakable part out of the last word and the button, however, it feels like an ugly hack, so we are looking for a clean CSS solution if possible.

UPDATE: Already found a solution here:

[How can I use a non-breaking space before an inline-block-default element, such as a <button>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072628/how-can-i-use-a-non-breaking-space-before-an-inline-block-default-element-such)

Comment: Not sure, but I think if you would change `button` to `a`, you should be able to use `white-space:nowrap;`.

Comment: Is the text dynamic? Can you modify the markup? https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/ZymdMr

Comment: Yes the text is dynamic

Comment: Must a line-break occur? Would it look odd if you ensured no wrapping - https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/gRQNZP

Comment: Or how about making the button grow when no space is available https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/mwQZoJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer here:

[How can I use a non-breaking space before an inline-block-default element, such as a <button>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072628/how-can-i-use-a-non-breaking-space-before-an-inline-block-default-element-such)

I had to wrap the button in a span, to make the browser think its still text and add `white-space: nowrap;` to the wrapping space.

The full markup:

```
button {
  display: inline;
}
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<label>This is a short text<span>&nbsp;<button>(?)</button></span><label>
```

Answer (score 2):

See if you can put a `<span>` around the last word + the button, and set the `<span>` to `{ display: inline-block; }`.

Demo:

```css
div {
  border: dotted 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

label>span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:160px">
  <label>This is a short help <span>text <button>(?)</button></span></label>
</div>
<div style="width:170px">
  <label>This is a short help <span>text <button>(?)</button></span></label>
</div>
<div style="width:180px">
  <label>This is a short help <span>text <button>(?)</button></span></label>
</div>
<div style="width:190px">
  <label>This is a short help <span>text <button>(?)</button></span></label>
</div>
<div style="width:200px">
  <label>This is a short help <span>text <button>(?)</button></span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: nice hack, adding `span` and `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Like I said in the original Post, the label text is dynamic, I am not going to split the sentence, However, if you update you answer with the technique from my own answer I accept it, thanks

Comment: No, it is fine this way, so everyone can see what approaches there are, and I'd even recommend to Accept your own answer since that is your preferred solution.

Comment: I would like to, but because I can accept it first after 2 days, I would prefer, to accept one from others, only add the other technique, so even like you said, people will see different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<label>This is a short help text <button>(?)</button></label>
</body>
<style>
label{
display:inline-block;
width:150px;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
</style>
```

> set width for the concern div or any tag and use
>   word-wrap:break-word;

Comment: check the updated code its working....add display:inline-block with code......it work   here is the codepen link https://codepen.io/mgkrish/pen/rwQEvd

Comment: It is breaking with the word only because of the fixed `140px`. Try to change the width to something dynamic like `30%` and change the window size, it will break between the text and the button.

Comment: do you want the text in two lines always?